# JMS destination in Jboss admin console has message count as blank instead of Zero

Tags: jboss, count, jms, message, jbossfuse

I am trying to check message count in JMS destination of JBoss EAP 6.1.
It is displaying Jboss message a [in flight messages in JMS destination displayed as blank which should have displayed a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xm43.jpg)s blank, it should have displayed count as some number i.e atleast zero if there are no messages in queue.

Any Idea why it displays blank, How to resolve this?

Please find screenshot of Jboss admin console for JMS destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the issue was with the my EAP, which somehow  got currupted. I have deleted my jboss eap . Now with fresh EAP, admin console is displaying the message count properly.

Answer (score 0):

It shows correct output once you select queue. Please find screen shot. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Varsha, For me it is not displaying count even after selecting queue

Comment: Which version of EAP you are using ?

Comment: Hi I m using JBoss EAP 6.1, I was able to see message count earlier as either zero or some number, now its blank